# Tensor products and "natural"

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

When reading about tensor products, the word "natural" often appears, for example "there exists a natural linear map/isomorphism" or "this is naturally defined as" or "this basis naturally induces another basis".
What is the exact definition of "natural" and what are some examples for "unnatural" things?

Comment: It can refer to natural transformation/natural isomorphism in the sense of category theory. Or it can just mean, the "obvious" thing or the "right" thing to do, the thing which follows from the definitions and stands out as the easiest definition to make, etc.